# How to make the child transitioning to the left and not scale?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the child image slide to the left and dissapear just like the parent. If your run the snipped now the image is scaling instead of sliding to the left.

How can I prevent the image to scale? And make the image slide to the left and dissapear just like the parent?

The transition will trigger by the media query.

This is my code.

```css
.parent {
  height: 130px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: ease all 0.3s;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/34490/keyboard-computer-keys-white.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 655px){
  .parent {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 1px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child">
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: what are you transitioning ?

Comment: I want to transition only the parent

Comment: Is this transition triggered by the media query?

Comment: Yes, if you open the snippet by full size and scale the window you can see the trantition. I only want the transition on the parent not on the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution that I could suggest you is set `visibility:visible;` for `.child` element and this works, but it is not supported by some browser. And this is only element which makes `child element` `visible` on `hiding parent` element.

> The visibility property can be used to hide an element while leaving
>   the space where it would have been. It can also hide rows or columns
>   of a table.

**Solution - 1** 
Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7z480doj/)

```css
.parent {
  height: 130px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: ease all 0.3s;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/34490/keyboard-computer-keys-white.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 655px){
  .parent {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 1px;
  }
  .child{
    width:180px;
    height:130px;
    visibility:visible;
    background-size:100% 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<span class="child">
</span>
</div>
```

**Solution - 2**
Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8p0yc440/)

Create `two` different element and `hide` below div using `opacity`.

```css
#bx{
  width:200px;
  height:130px;
  background:#111;
  transition: ease all 0.3s;
}
#b{
  width:200px;
  height:120px;
  top:13px;
  left:8px;
  position:absolute;
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/34490/keyboard-computer-keys-white.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size:100%;
  margin-left:0;
  transition: ease all 0.3s;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 655px){
  #bx{
    width:1px;
    opacity:0;
  }
  #b{
        margin-left:-220px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="bx"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want the child also to disappear. If you size the window the parent disapears to the left, but the image scales i want it to disapear also to the left. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Welcome @Dave, and check second updated solution and jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the `.child` disappears with parent is because:

1. ...the `.child's` height and width are 100% of `.parent`. Guess what `.child's height and width are when`.parent's` width and height are 1px and 130px (hint: what's a 100% of 1px and 100% of 130px?)
2. Another reason is because all children of an element that has `visibility:hidden` will be hidden as well, **unless a child element has `visibility: visible` explicitly set** (must have it as a declared CSS rule)

So knowing this, we should counter those properties when that MQ (media query) kicks in. Details are commented in the Snippet below:

> ```
> .child {
>   width: 100%;
>   height: 100%;
>   background-size: contain;
>   text-indent: -9999px;
>   display: block;
>   background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/34490/keyboard-computer-keys-white.jpg);
>   background-repeat: no-repeat;
>   background-position: center center;
>   /* These properties were added so that `.child` is in the normal
>   || "flow" to which `.parent` is not due to it having `position: fixed`
>   */
>   position: relative;
>   right: 0;
>   bottom: 0;
> }
>
> @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
>   .parent {
>     visibility: hidden;
>     width: 1px;
>   }
>   /* This ruleset will counter the properties
>   || that were previously discussed
>   */
>   .child {
>     visibility: visible;
>     min-width: 180px;
>     min-height: 130px;
>   }
> }
> ```

**SNIPPET**

```css
.parent {
  height: 130px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/34490/keyboard-computer-keys-white.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .parent {
    width: 1px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: width 0.3s ease;
  }
  .child {
    visibility: visible;
    max-width: 0px;
    min-height: 130px;
    transition: transform 1s ease-out;
    transform: translateX(-180px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child">
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want the child also to disappear. If you size the window the parent disapears to the left, but the image scales. i want it to disapear also to the left. Sorry for my English.

Comment: @Dave How do you want the image to disappear? You want it to slide to the left instead of swinging like a door:?

Comment: Yes, I want to slide the image to the left and dissapear just like the parent. If your run the snipped now the image is scaling instead of sliding to the left.

Comment: I see you just want the child's width to shrink giving the appearance of it sliding. Standby.

Comment: @Dave Ok this time it's a transformX

Comment: Thanks zer00ne. but the image is just disappearing now, it doesn't shrink to the left.

Comment: I want it to shrinkt to the left en then disappear

Answer (score 0):

Check out example that you need to understand.

```css
.sibling {
    width:300px;
    height:56px;
    background-color:hsla(40, 50%, 60%, .6);
    position:absolute;
    left:240px;
}
.parent {
    visibility:visible;
    width:170px;
    height:170px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, hsla(10, 90%, 50%, 1) 50%, hsla(100, 90%, 50%, .0) 50%);
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transition:0s;
    transition:0s;
}

.sibling:hover ~ .parent {
    visibility:visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in .2s;
    transition: .6s ease-in .2s;
}
.child {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, hsla(5, 35%, 50%, 1) 50%, hsla(100, 90%, 50%, .0) 50%);
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition:0s;
    transition:0s;
}
.sibling:hover ~ .parent > .child {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transition: .1s ease-in .9s;
    transition: .1s ease-in .9s;
}
```

```html
<div class="sibling"></div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks cool, but it doesn't do anything the OP wants, like disappearing.